# Trying to compile with codelite/g++

Tags: c++, c, build, g++, codelite

I am new to codelite and have set up a new g++ Project:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

However, if I click 'Build Active Project' the Build ouput says:

> /bin/sh -c ' -j 1 -e -f  Makefile'
>       /bin/sh: 1: -j: not found
>       0 errors, 0 warnings

I tried the by default generated Makefile as well as a custom one. What is  wrong here that the build operation fails without any error?

---

I'm using following software:
**OS:** *Ubuntu 14.04.01 LTS 64bit*, as a virtual machine with Windows 7 as Host
**IDE:** *CodeLite 7.0 for Trusty Tahr* (=Ubuntu 14.04)
**Compiler, Tools:** I installed g++ and gdb from the command line, in case I forgot something, I listed the [output of `apt list`](http://pastebin.de/raw/?id=65415)

Comment: **OS:** Ubuntu 14.04.01 LTS 64bit, as a virtual machine with Windows 7 as Host **CodeLite:** Version 7.0 for Trusty Tahr (=Ubuntu 14.04)
I installed g++ and gdb from the command line

Comment: What do you have in 'Settings... -> Build Settings... -> Compiler : Make' of your toolchain ?

Comment: For the compiler gnu g++, it's `-j 1`

Comment: I think it should be `make -j 1` instead. (check also that you have `make` installed).

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! However, if I run/debug the program its console immediately closes; if I drop a breakpoint at `return 0;` it shows me at the first line: `&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted\n"`Is there a way I can properly view the program's output? (I have checked the "output" tab in codelite.) *P.S.:* Repost your previous comment and I'll accept it as answer asap.

Comment: You have the output Pane (F1) (for program output) and the debugger Pane (Ctrl-D) (for gdb output), each one have an output tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 'Settings... -> Build Settings... -> Compiler : Make'

You should have:

```
make -j 1
```

And make sure that make is installed on your machine.